# Does Stack Overflow provide any means for an existing Q&A forum to migrate to SO?

Tags: feature-request

In the [ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System) community we have been using our own Q&A forum, [ROS Answers](https://answers.ros.org/questions/). That forum is extremely similar to the way SO works. One might even wonder whether it was purposefully designed after SO. I wasn't around when that decision was made, but to me it seems that it would have been better to just use SO directly instead, creating the appropriate tags as needed.

So my question is this: Does SO provide, or would consider providing, an import feature that would allow an existing Q&A forum such as ROS Answers to migrate to SO? By this I mean a way to import all existing questions and answers, including comments, and ideally also the reputation of users. I wouldn't expect this to be trivial. The community would clearly need to be the one providing the data in whatever format SO would require. But in principle, is this conceivable?

If not into SO, or another existing Stack Exchange network like [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/), would it be possible to create a new Stack Exchange Network from a data-dump like that?

Comment: I'm sure it's *possible*. However, whether or not it's *plausible* is another matter. You may like to suggest a "beta site" on the Stack Exchange network, but probably best to ask that on the [Main Meta Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). The process *may* involve "crossing," "silver" and "palms" (but not necessarily in that order).

Comment: The vast majority of these questions do *not* look like they would be on-topic for Stack Overflow. However, they might be a good fit for a new or existing Stack Exchange site. That's a discussion that really should be had on the global Meta site, [Meta.SE]. I'd migrate this question there, but based on the title and body, you seem to have been thinking specifically of migrating to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Christian, I agree with Cody. I think you should edit the question and then flag it for migration to [meta.SE].

Comment: you may be interested in examples of sites that migrated to Stack Exchange in the past, namely [MathOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277069/165773) and [Hashcode.ru](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316022/165773)

Answer (score 3):

Having taken a short tour of your site, I can see that its layout and structure are, indeed, very similar to those of the SE system. However, although I imagine that it would be relatively straightforward (but not trivial) for SE staff (their developers are a pretty smart bunch, by all accounts) to work up software that could quickly convert the databases of questions, answers, badges, karma (love that, BTW*) and so forth, the main issue I would foresee is that of user accounts. You can't just auto-migrate those—each individual would have to 'sign up' and agree to SE's Terms and Conditions, for example.

There would also be potential 'snags' with users who already have accounts/profiles on the SE network, and with site moderators (SE mods have even stricter Terms and Conditions they must agree to).

In terms of where your forum would best fit on SE—I think your suggestion of [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) looks to be the most likely candidate. But again, there could be snags. Obviously, I can't speak for the staff, but it may be best to *initially* create a new (beta) site and then, if that goes well, it would be *quick and painless* to merge that with the existing Robotics site (subject, of course, to community and staff approval). (In terms of questions, your existing ROS site is close to 10 times the size of the SE Robotics site!)

(And, to put my 'lame joke'—in [my initial comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402427/does-stackoverflow-provide-any-means-for-an-existing-qa-forum-to-migrate-to-so#comment804829_402427)—about money to rest: I really can't see the bean counters being, in any way, bothered by such a merger. You are, effectively, providing a ready-made (and quite substantial) forum on which advertisements and other revenue-generators can be released.)

---

* Trying to explain to my fiancée and her family (Lao/Thai) what "reputation" was, the closest we could get was "Green Bubble Merit!"