# Where should [ros] questions be posted?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation, network-sites

- As already mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402427/does-stack-overflow-provide-any-means-for-an-existing-qa-forum-to-migrate-to-so/402428#402428), the robotics community is used to asking their questions on a different forum *very* similar to the Stack Exchange Network: [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org). There are about 25 questions posted there each day. But I understand that from the SE's perspective this is probably seen as competition rather than a reason to remove ROS-related questions from this network.
- On Stack Overflow we have a special tag [ros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ros) that gets about 3-4 questions each day.
- On the SE Network there is also a community [robotics.stackexchange.com](https://robotics.stackexchange.com) where ROS-related questions have a home. It gets about 5-6 questions each day.

Even if we are just talking about the last two sites: what is the canonical place to ask a ROS-question?

If there is already a whole community on the SE Network that's just about robotics, wouldn't the SO [ros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ros) tag, by definition, contain only off-topic questions?

Comment: _” If there already is a whole community in the SE-Network that's just about robotics, wouldn't the SO-ros-tag by definition contain only off-topic questions?”_. No, that something is on-topic elsewhere does not make it off-topic here. There is a lot of overlap among several network sites’ scopes.

Comment: Similar situation, posted on Meta.Robotic.SE in 2018: [Topic scope of “Robotics”](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1356/17104)

Comment: Regarding @yivi's comment, see, e.g., [Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/215552)